# How can I smooth a CapsuleShape[] visualization?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, visualization, version-11.3

Simple question I can't figure out. Is it possible to smooth the edge faces of a capsule, or is this inherent to the mesh underlying the capsule? This is just for visualization purposes, I don't really care about changing any inherent properties of the mesh/region.

Maybe a workaround would be some sort of lighting option that ignores the edges? Which option(s) would that be?

**Note**: I'm on Windows 10 and MMA 13.1.

Thanks!

```
myCapsules = {CapsuleShape[{{-0.5, 0., 0.}, {0.5, 0., 0.}}, 5.], 
 CapsuleShape[{{-7.55082, 3.30872, -3.61074}, {-7.13133, 
    3.12491, -3.41015}}, 5.]};

Graphics3D[myCapsules, ViewPoint -> Front, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}]
```

[image]

Comment: This may be OS and version dependent. I am on MMA 12.3.1 on Win10-64 and [the results of your unmodified code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNmqh.png) are much, much smoother already.

Comment: @MarcoB That's strange, I'd think the latest version would render the best XD. Or maybe it is Windows. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get better-looking results if I use `Tube[]` instead, and tweak the internal `"TubePoints"` setting:

```
Graphics3D[{Tube @@@ myCapsules}, ViewPoint -> Front,
           Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 30}]
```

[image: short, fat tubes]

I am not aware if there's a similar internal option setting corresponding to `CapsuleShape[]`, which would be a direct answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

To increase the quality of the picture, you may increase the "SplinePoints":

```
Graphics3D[myCapsules, ViewPoint -> Front, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}, Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 15}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Or use `AccuracyGoal -> 3` in `DiscretizeRegion`.

```
myCapsules = {CapsuleShape[{{-0.5, 0., 0.}, {0.5, 0., 0.}}, 5.], 
   CapsuleShape[{{-7.55082, 3.30872, -3.61074}, {-7.13133, 
      3.12491, -3.41015}}, 5.]};
myCapsules = 
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#, AccuracyGoal -> 3] & /@ myCapsules
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], myCapsules}, ViewPoint -> Front, Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}]
```

[image]